# how to access the array object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have an array like

```
Array ( 
[result] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                                    [subs_msg_id] => 31 
                                    [subscriber_id] => 13 
                                    [from_subs_user_id] => 92 
                                    [from_subs_email] => test@gmail.com 
                                    [message_text] =>mmmmmmmmmmmyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
                                 )
[message_time] => 1428161519 
                ) 
     )
$this->load->view('reply_message_form',$this->data);
```

i want it access [from_subs_email] element in view page reply_message_form

how do i access that? in codeigniter view

Comment: You want foreach loop. or this std class object array is always a single index array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller
you should append array to data like this:

```
$data = array();
$data['message'] = Array (....);
$this->load->view('reply_message_form', $data);
```

Then in view you can access to from_subs_email like this:

```
<?php echo $message['result'][0]->from_subs_email; ?>
```

Or you can loop in $message array to print information